# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server

Please friends help me. I can't find out where am going wrong. All the     variables I need to update are so far good, but the actual update statement returns an error saying

> "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on  null"

Below is a small piece of my php code:

```
      $name_image=basename($_FILES[$idx]["name"]["$key"]);         
      $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");           
      $email_insert = $_SESSION['email'];
      $sql_upl ="UPDATE forepost_users SET profile_picture  ='$name_image',lastmodified ='$time' WHERE email_address=?";             
      $SQL_statement_upl= $this->conn->prepare($sql_upl);
      $SQL_statement_upl->bindParam(1,$email_insert);
      $SQL_statement_upl->execute();
```

Comment: This `SET profile_picture  ='$name_image',lastmodified ='$time'` won't insert the `$name_image` and `$time` values into your prepared statement. Bind them as parameters instead?

Comment: Thank let me try that

Comment: You should var_dump `$this->conn` and make sure it's returning what you expect

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems.

1. Your `$conn` isn't initialized which is why you're getting this error because `$conn` is null and you're attempting to call a member function of a null  object.

Please include your `$conn` initialization code if you need assistance resolving issues with that.

2. Your prepared statement is invalid.

`SET profile_picture  ='$name_image',lastmodified ='$time'`

This part of your `UPDATE` statement will not insert the values of `$name_image` and `$time` into the SQL statement. Remember this is a 'prepared statement', so you're creating a SQL template that will be executed multiple times. Each time it is executed, you're passing the values into the SQL statement through the bound parameters.

So change your prepared statement to:

`"UPDATE forepost_users SET profile_picture = ?, lastmodified = ? WHERE email_address = ?"`

Then bind each of the parameters before execution:

```
$SQL_statement_upl->bindParam(1,$name_image);
$SQL_statement_upl->bindParam(2,$time);
$SQL_statement_upl->bindParam(3,$_email_insert);
```

Comment: i have tried using bind parameters as pointed above but  i keep getting the same error

Comment: Have you checked that your three variables have values? Are any of them null? Is your database connection `$conn` actually been initialized?

Comment: yeah my values are not empty but the lastmodified column is empty in my database , could that be a problem ?

Comment: Are you definitely sure your `$conn` is initialized? Can you share that part of your code please?

Comment: Yeah you were right, i had not initialize my conn variable properly. i have corrected that and now its working fine. Thank you very much.